# wanted to use results of find command in custom script that i am building

Tags: shell

I want to validate my XML's for well-formed ness, but some of my files are not having a single root (which is fine as per business req eg. `<ri>...</ri><ri>..</ri>` is valid xml in my context) , xmlwf can do this, but it flags out a file if it's not having single root, So wanted to build a custom script which internally uses xmlwf, my custom script should do below,

iterate through list of files passed as input  (eg. sample.xml or s*.xml or *.xml)
for each file prepare a temporary file as `<A>+contents of file+</A>` 
and call xmlwf on that temp file,
Can some one help on this?

Comment: Given that, how would you be able to solve the problem of multiple roots?

Comment: Sorry, but StackOverflow isn't a free coding service. You seem to understand the issues, why not learn how to write a `for` loop (search here for `[bash] for loop`. Be sure to work on a copy of your data and confirm it is working as needed before you apply it to your "real" data. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks shelter - reason for providing those details is to give the picture of what I am doing to understand why and where I am struck. but will keep that in mind

Comment: One comment: your remark about multiple root elements being "valid xml in my content" doesn't hold water. Multiple root elements are not well-formed xml, and therefore by definition _never_ valid, no matter the context!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add text to the beginning and end of the file using cat and bash, so that your file has a root added to it for validation purposes.

`cat <(echo '<root>') sample.xml <(echo '</root>') | xmlwf`

This way you don't need to write temporary files out.